# Is there a foreground equivalent to background-image in css?

Tags: html, css, foreground

I want to add some shine to an element on webpage. I would prefer if I don't have to add additional html to the page. I want the image to appear in front of the element rather than behind. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Are the dimensions of the element fixed?

Comment: Yes they are. More charcters to allow me to comment.

Comment: I'm  trying to make it work with the :after psuedo-element now...

Comment: "I would prefer if I don't have to add additional html to the page." That's not possible: You have to use a wrapper element and a pseudo-element `(::before)` as you see in [Rob W's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12660106/478018), or an `<img>` element as you see in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71449486/478018).

Answer (score 78, accepted):

To achieve a "foreground image" (without extra HTML code), you can use a pseudo-element (`::before` / `:before`) **plus the CSS [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events)**. The last property is needed so that the user can actually click through the layer "as if it did not exist".

Here's an example (using a colour whose alpha channel is 50% so that you can see that the real elements can actually be focused). http://jsfiddle.net/JxNdT/

```css
#cont {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  /*To show the boundaries of the element*/
}

#cont:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  Test<br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="edit">
</div>
```

​
PS. I picked the `::before` pseudo-element, because that naturally leads to the correct positioning. If I pick `::after`, then I have to add `position:relative;` to the real element (`#cont`), and `top:0;left:0;` to the pseudo-element (`::after`).

---

PPS. To get the **foreground effect on elements without a fixed size**, an additional element is needed. This wrapper element requires the `position:relative;display:inline-block;` styles. Set the `width` and `height` of the pseudo-element to `100%`, and the pseudo-element will stretch to the width and height of the wrapper element. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JxNdT/1/.

Comment: great stuff! As the image already has alpha-transparency, i wont need the background-element, but apart from i'll just copy paste!

Comment: Just curious, is there a similair solution if the element size is not static?

Comment: @KristofferNolgren You need a wrapper which has `position:relative;` (and `display:inline-block;`), then use `100%` for `width` and `height` on the pseudo-element. The pseudo-element will stretch to the width and height of the wrapper element. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JxNdT/1/

Comment: @RobW You don't need a wrapper and you can stretch the absolutely positioned `:after` pseudo-element with *trbl* properties all set to 0; see updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JxNdT/2/

Comment: @FelipeAls Great! I didn't even consider that option.

Comment: +1 for a creative approach and while this works perfectly in chrome under IE-8 the color still appears behind the content. If i find a solution for older browsers ill post it here.

Comment: @Reahreic did you find a solution?

Comment: Nice solution! I actually had to use z-index to make it completely work but that was specific to my situation I guess

Answer (score 4):

If you need a white-transparent foreground

This is for future visitors like me who are considering adding a white-transparent foreground to an element to communicate that it's hidden / disabled for instance. You can often achieve your goal by simply lowering the `opacity` below 1:

```css
.is-hidden {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
visible
<span class="is-hidden">hidden</span>
visible
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this css

```
#yourImage
{
z-index: 1; 
}
```

**NOTE**

Set the `z-index` to index greater the the `z-index` of the element over which you are putting the image.

If you have not specified any `z-index` then `1` would do the work.

You can also set `z-index` to `-1`,in that case the image would always be at `background`!

Comment: The `z-index` property works only on positioned (`absolute`, `relative` or `fixed`) elements.

Answer (score 0):

A neat solution: box-sizing + padding-left, see more at [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/replace-the-image-in-an-img-with-css/)

Somewhere in your HTML:

```
<img id="test_replacement" src="test.png" alt="test" />
```

The CSS for replacing the image (on hovering)

```
#test_replacement {
    width: 200px; //must be the size of your image (and the replacement one)
    height: 200px; //idem
    display: block;
}
#test_replacement:hover {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-image: url('somewhere/other_image.png');
    padding-left: 200px; //at least the size of the width
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an absolutely positioned `<img>` element:

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.3;
  pointer-events: none;
}

iframe {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rET57.jpg" alt="Foreground image">

<iframe src="https://example.com/"></iframe>
```