# Show colour overlay on images NOT in selector

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I'm trying to amend the jQuery I have right now which currently will display a colour on top of an image which is hovered over.

I instead need it to display the hover-over colour on all OTHER images when one is hovered over. Not to certain on the changes in this particular case.

So out of 6 images, if I mouse over 2, it will display the overlay on 1,3,4,5,6.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">
<img src="http://mirrorchecker.com/images/rod_160.png" width="160" class="company-image" />
<div class="company-image-overlay"></div>
<img src="http://mirrorchecker.com/images/rod_160.png" width="160" class="company-image" />
<div class="company-image-overlay"></div>
<img src="http://mirrorchecker.com/images/rod_160.png" width="160" class="company-image" />
<div class="company-image-overlay"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.company-image-overlay {
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    background-color: #ffb00f;
    border-radius: 15px;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0.5em;
    display:none;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.wrap').mouseover(function () {
    $('.company-image-overlay').show();
}).mouseout(function () {
     $('.company-image-overlay').hide();
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/AUzKE/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something very similar to `Jacob`, where I've changed much of the structure, but I've done it in a much simpler/cleaner/easier way. Check this out:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="company-image">
        <img src="http://mirrorchecker.com/images/rod_160.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="company-image">
        <img src="http://mirrorchecker.com/images/rod_160.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="company-image">
        <img src="http://mirrorchecker.com/images/rod_160.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.company-image {
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.company-image > img {
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.company-image:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    background: rgba(255, 176, 15, 0.5); /* Adjust this last value to adjust the opacity of the overlay */
    border-radius: 15px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.company-image.overlay-show:before{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('.company-image').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).siblings('.company-image').addClass('overlay-show');
}).mouseout(function () {
    $(this).siblings('.company-image').removeClass('overlay-show');
});
```

The use of the `:before` psudo element comes from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659953/is-there-a-foreground-equivalent-to-background-image-in-css). It's easier to manipulate classes than the pseudo elements themselves so that's why I used a class to make the overlay show. The jQuery siblings selector takes the `.company-image` class selector as well to assure that it only gets the other relevant elements. If for some reason you can't put all the images inside a single parent `div` then you'd have to use `$('.company-image').not(this)` selector instead, thanks goes to `Good Luck`.

[Here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AUzKE/745/)

Comment: Is it possible to have the overlay effect only the img tag itself rather than the div class surrounding it?

Comment: [Not using the `:before` tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843035/does-before-not-work-on-img-elements) but you could try the technique on that link

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I've modified your JSFiddle.

First of all I've changed the method of tinting. I've wrapped each image in a tint which goes behind the image and is always there, with a bright red background in this case. Tinting the image is then achieved by changing the opacity of the image. *Note (in the CSS on the JSFiddle) that I've defined by px the background tint so that you don't get a bit sticking out at the bottom. (There are other ways of doing this, but the px solution was quick).*

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="background-tint"><img src="http://mirrorchecker.com/images/rod_160.png" width="160" class="company-image" /></div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
<div class="background-tint"><img src="http://mirrorchecker.com/images/rod_160.png" width="160" class="company-image" /></div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
<div class="background-tint"><img src="http://mirrorchecker.com/images/rod_160.png" width="160" class="company-image" /></div>
</div>
```

Then the Jquery is quite simple. On hover you modify the opacity of all images to 0.5, and then change specifically the opacity of the image you're hovering over *back* to 1.

```
$('.wrap img').mouseover(function () {
$('.wrap img').css('opacity', '0.5'); 
$(this).css('opacity', '1'); 
}).mouseout(function () {
$('.wrap img').css('opacity', '1'); 
});
```

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AUzKE/713/**

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.not(this)`:

```
$('.wrap div').mouseover(function () {
    $('.wrap div').not(this).children('.company-image-overlay').show();
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AUzKE/717/)